# Michelson-Morley experiment revisited under the light of special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Taking into account the composition of speeds in special relativity,
lets suppose that a Michelson-Morley interferometer is moving at a speed of $\vec{v}$: the speed of Earth relative to the local space-time.

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Michelson-morley_calculations.svg]

Under newtonian mechnics, the conclusion of the Michelson-Morley was of course that either $\vec v = \vec 0$ or that $\vec v$ is a meaningless concept and hence there is no aether.

---

Under special relativity: $$\forall \vec v,  \vec c + \vec v = \vec c$$

Hence the speed of the photons on the (supposed) transversal $t$ and longitudinal $l$ arms have a speed of the same value: $c$, and their time to travel is independtly of $\vec v$
$$T_t = T_l = 2L/c$$.

Consequently in special relativity any (hypothetic) speed $\vec v$ of the earth relative to any form of space-time (I prefer this term to the one of aether) **can not** be detected with such an interferometer because it is heavily based on the speed of light.

---

How starting from this basic reasonning can anyone conclude that$$\vec v = \vec 0$$ ?

How can anyone conclude that such a$$\vec v$$ doesn't mean anything?

Were other experiments conducted so as to be less directly dependant of the speed of light?

Comment: Do you understand how the analogous experiment with waves in a medium differs? At the end of the 19th century it was assumed that waves traveled in media, so the expectations for the experiment were based on calculations that made that assumption.

Comment: "The speed of Earth relative to the local space-time" - there is no such thing as "relative to local space-time"

Comment: → dmckee: it is rather clear that Michelson worked on the hypothesis the model of the sound (in gaz, liquid or solid) was transposable to light (in an hypothetic aether).

Comment: Are you asking what would be predicted in special relativity? If so, velocity "relative to the local space-time" is meaningless. Or are you asking what would be predicted in an aether theory, assuming rulers moving relative to the aether don't contract and clocks moving relative to the aether don't run slow? If so, you should say "relative to the aether", not "relative to the local space-time". If neither of these, please elaborate.

Comment: → Hypnosifl: "Are you asking what would be predicted in special relativity?": no I didn't write this question. Moreover I used one of its results (special relativity).

Comment: → Hypnosifl: taking into account special relativity, how (today) may anyone conclude that a speed Michelson wanted to measure can be $\vec 0$? The term of revisited in the title is meaningful.

Comment: → Hypnosifl: is there now an experiment taking into account the special relativity and proving that this hypothetic $\vec v = \vec 0$? The term hypothetic is meaningful here.

Comment: I think you are confused, daniel. The Michelson-Morley calculation the time difference was predicated on a Newtonian concept of velocity addition **and** on the existence of a luminiferous aether. That $\vec v$ is the velocity of the Earth with respect to the supposed aether. That makes no sense in special relativity. SR says the aether doesn't exist. There is no $\vec v$ in special relativity.

Comment: → David: I made the foolish hypothesis I'm not that confused. I know that Michelson experiment was build on top of newtonian mechanics. I know what SR concluded about the hypothesis of the aether and the meaningless of the concept of a $\vec v$ relative to nothing.
Please read my question :).
If something is fully wrong, tell it, I'll (try to) fix it.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos - Please response to people with an @ symbol before their username, not an arrow--the site software is designed to send people an alert if a comment is made with an @ symbol before their name, if the symbol is different they may not be alerted so they won't see your message unless they happen to come back to take another look at the question.

Comment: [@Hypnosifl] → Hypnosifl: Sorry but my use of the symbol `@` which means `at` in the sense of the technical address or location **where** something or someone is. As in `@IP`, `@home`, `@London` … This is a personnal graphical convention I use since the beginning of the E-mail. I use the `→` to designate either a mathematical function or to who a text or comment is adressed. This is also a personnal graphical convention I use since… a long time with a clear understanding of everyone. It is in no way intended to fire any software function.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos - Just so you know, I didn't get an alert about your above comment either, I only discovered you had replied just now because I happened to go back and look for this thread. So apparently putting a bracket before the @ also prevents the board software from sending an alert to the person you are replying to. Obviously you're free to use whatever convention you want, but if you don't use the @ convention then the people you're trying to talk to may never notice that you replied to their comments.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: $\vec v = \vec 0$ is not the general conclusion of the MM. It was that speed of light is invariant with the direction.

Answer (score 1):

They expected that light would go the "dotted path", which is longer than the "solid" path thanks to the relative motion $v$, so that it arrives later than the other ray, so that there would be
constructive / destructive interference between
the two rays which would happen below the mirror,
so they expected to see light/dark interference patterns.

But no patterns were visible, so I believe the chain of reasoning was like this:

no interference $\Rightarrow$ no dotted path $\Rightarrow$ $v = 0$

Then the experiment was rotated and they tried again without success.

$\Rightarrow$ $v = 0$ in every direction! $\Rightarrow$ something is wrong

SRT explanation: light doesn't care about $v \ne 0$, it will arrive just at the same time than its other ray, so it is ok to see no interfernce pattern.

Comment: That $+(v_1, v_2) \ne v_1 + v_2$ is indeed more scientific than my sloppy "doesn't care". :-)

Comment: This conclusion was right with the addition of speeds within newtonian mechanics: $\vec c + \vec v = \vec c + \vec v$. But we all know (now) that this hypothesis context was wrong. Within the context of SR, the Michelson-Morley experiment looks like a tautology.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos - What do you mean by "tautology"? Of course SR predicts that the same interference pattern will be seen regardless of the interferometer's velocity relative to any arbitrarily-chosen reference frame, but I don't see how this is more "tautologous" then any other prediction, like the prediction that energy will be conserved. And since the aether theory predicts something different, it is a good test of which theory's predictions are correct--experiments aren't just done "within the context of" a particular theory, they can test one theory vs. another.

Comment: What does the Michelson-Morley experiment demonstrate **within** the hypothesis frame of the SR **and not** within the hypothesis frame of an aether and the newtonian mechanics?

Comment: @daniel Azuelos - Again, experiments aren't really done "within" a particular hypothesis frame, they just give real-world empirical results which can then be compared to the theoretical predictions of various theories/hypothesis frames, to see which theories correctly predict those results and which ones give predictions that conflict with the real-world results. The fact that the same interference pattern is seen even in multiple experiments where the device has different rest frames is an observation that agrees with the predictions of SR, but not with those of traditional aether theories.

Comment: But M-M didn't measure L -- they just assumed v<>0 and compared the interference to an orthogonal v.  SR says that L shortens when it is parallel to v;  that is the tautology (there may indeed be an aether, but you can't observe it).